# How can I avoid having lots of conditional instantiations at the top of a sitewide javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I have a single JS file that I use across the whole of my app. The top of it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if( $('#element-a').length ) {
        var featureA = new ElementAFeature( $('#element-a') );
    }

    if( $('#element-b').length ) {
        var featureB = new ElementBFeature( $('#element-b') );
    }

    // repeat ad nauseam for elements C thru Z etc etc
});

// actual objects and logic go here
```

It works, but it's sort of ugly. Short of running different scripts on different pages, is there any way of tidying this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each page do something like this

```
window.MYAPP = window.MYAPP || {};
window.MYAPP.element = $("page-element");
window.MYAPP.feature = new ElementXFeature(window.MYAPP.element);
```

then modify your init script to

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   var feature = window.MYAPP.feature;
   //Use feature here.
});
```

If you are writing a lot of specific init code for each page you might wanna consider having both a global init method and defining a local one for each page and pass any context needed from the global init.

```
window.MYAPP.initMethod = function(context) {}

//in global init
if (typeof window.MYAPP.initMethod === "function") {
    window.MYAPP.initMethod({ pageSpecificSetting : 0});
}
```